# Install python package from private artifactory behind VPN

Tags: github-actions, artifactory, vpn, python-packaging, openvpn

I have a Github Actions CI/CD for my python packages which has dependency on a private repository. Moreover, that repository is behind VPN which obviously breaks my installation and testing pipeline.

Is there a way to configure VPN for Github Actions task to make it work?

Should I set-up some kind of proxy and have bastion host within vpn?

What is the recommendable approach for such a case?

Comment: The issue is not with specifying extra index url `--extra-index-url` but how to deal with vpn limitation from ci/cd side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found two possible options to deal with this issue:

1. Create an Github Actions runner instance within your VPC which has an access to resources within VPN and [register to your gh project](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/adding-self-hosted-runners)
2. Create an instance within VPC and make it as a proxy for pip, so it would be able to access your artifactory.

```bash
$ pip install --proxy http://<usr_name>:<password>@<proxyserver_name>:<port_number> <pkg_name>
```